# Why does a single variable give 0.09999 instead of 0.1 ?

Tags: vb.net, operation

This is not really a big question but I'm very curious and I would like to know why, after an operation like "1.1 - 1" (1.1 as Single, 1 as Integer), the result is equal to 0.09999 and not 1 (1.1-1=0.1, naturally).

I have replaced the integer "1" with a single "1.0" and it's working correctly.

Thanks, and sorry for my english.

A.

Comment: Search for "float (or double) format" and "float (or double) precission loss". You can also use a `decimal` format.

Comment: Because of floating point (limited) precision. Read [this](https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~dwharder/NumericalAnalysis/02Numerics/Double/paper.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

You need to know how data is stored in memory, first take a look at integers e.g. `int`, `short`, `unsigned long long` they are stored in memory and every different bits configuration means different number so its fine, the same situation is with `float` numbers, different bits configuration means different number, so lets look at limits of types. Compare `int` and `float` both of them are 32-bit numbers. `int` limit is `–2147483648 to 2147483647` 4294967296 different values so how about `float`

```
#define FLT_MAX 3.402823466e+38F /* max value */
#define FLT_MIN 1.175494351e-38F /* min positive value */
```

So as you see range is much much wider, but amount of different values are the same so you cannot have such good precision, also you can read more about `float` standart IEEE754 [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) or [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985)